# How to cut certain rows and insert before a certain row in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to cut certain rows and insert before a certain row in excel, I am unable to do this in a reliable fashion.

Note: I should be able to remove the lines from which it was cut originally, currently it doesn't seem to happen and I have to manually remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlight the row by clicking of the row number then press Ctrl+X then click on the row number below the row were you intend to insert the cut rows then press Ctrl+V.